# Would the destruction of Deimos have any lasting geological impact on Mars?

Tags: mars

This question is inspired by events in the science fiction series: [The Expanse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Expanse_(TV_series)). To summarize, Deimos is blown up in a retaliatory strike.

One character laments about how she would feel if Earth's moon was destroyed, to which another replies that it's not the same as Deimos is barely visible from the surface of Mars.

That part I did know. But what I'm curious to know is whether there would be any kind of geological impact on Mars if something happened to either of it's moons.

Would any changes be detectable or even noticeable to Mars inhabitants?

Comment: *Welcome to Space!* I made some small changes to the wording to help fit your question to the general style of Stack Exchange. Please double check and make sure you're happy with it, and feel free to edit further. Thanks!

Comment: I would not count out the visibility of Deimos from the surface of Mars.  The Martian rover Curiosity [has observed Deimos transiting the Sun](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2012/10031608-curiosity-catches-sunspots.html).  Our lamenting character would have a legitimate case.

Comment: The changes work. Thank you @uhoh. Oscar Lanzi I had wondered because in The Martian, Mark Whatney uses one of he moons to navigate and I couldn't remember if it was Phobos or Deimos. And I remembered a book I had read in middle school that might be outdated now saying that one of the moons was like a bright dot in the Martian sky.